# Big decimal add returns wrong value

Tags: java, math

I want to random amounts and the sum of these. Code is

```
    BigDecimal amountA=myUtils.getRandomAmount(1, 100000);
    BigDecimal amountB=myUtils.getRandomAmount(1, 100000);
    BigDecimal sum=amountA;
    sum.add(amountB);
    logger.info("a: {} b: {} sum: {}", amountA, amountB, sum);
```

Output is:
a: 68463.76 b: 99445.71 sum: 68463.76

Why is sum not 68463.76 + 99445.71 but only amountA?
And how can I solve it, of course?

Comment: `BigDecimal` is immutable. You need to reassign the value: `sum = sum.add(amountB)`. Or in one go: `sum = amountA.add(amountB)`.

Comment: read the `add`method javadoc

Comment: Because you are doing `BigDecimal sum=amountA;` where as you want to `BigDecimal sum= amountA.add(amountB);`

Comment: stupid me... I was 100% sure, that it worked before, but of course I must be wrong

Answer (score 2):

it is because `BigDecimal` is immutable. This means that once created, its value cannot be changed. As a result, when you apply mathematical operations on `BigDecimal` you'll get the result as a new object, through the return, for example:

```java
BigDecimal sum=amountA.add(amountB);
```

Read more about immutability here: https://www.baeldung.com/java-immutable-object

Answer (score -2):

You should be using the wrong BigDecimal method.

```
BigDecimal amountA=myUtils.getRandomAmount(1, 100000);
BigDecimal amountB=myUtils.getRandomAmount(1, 100000);
BigDecimal sum=amountA;
sum = sum.add(amountB);
logger.info("a: {} b: {} sum: {}", amountA, amountB, sum);
```

Comment: They're using the right method, just doing the wrong thing with the result of that method.